# undefined method `build' for Doorkeeper::Request::Assertion:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper

Currently, I'm building an application that can login via fb/g+ using doorkeeper and doorkeeper-grant_assertion. Previously, everything is okay but just a sudden I encounter this problem which is unfamiliar to me and even I already google it still can't find someone who had encounter this problem.

```
class Oauth::TokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController

  def create
    response = authorize_response
    self.headers.merge! response.headers
    self.response_body = 
      if response.status == :ok
        json_success( response )
      else
        json_fail( response )
      end
  end

end
```

**UPDATE**

```
 - doorkeeper (3.0.1) lib/doorkeeper/server.rb:16:in `token_request'
 - doorkeeper (3.0.1) app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb:38:in `strategy'
 - doorkeeper (3.0.1) app/controllers/doorkeeper/tokens_controller.rb:42:in `authorize_response'
 - app/controllers/oauth/tokens_controller.rb:4:in `create'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:815:in `call'
 - omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
 - omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
 - omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
 - omniauth (1.3.1) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
 - rack-attack (4.4.1) lib/rack/attack.rb:107:in `call'
 - warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 - warden (1.2.6) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
 - activerecord (4.2.5.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:377:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
 - quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
 - request_store (1.3.0) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:9:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
 - activesupport (4.2.5.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
 - actionpack (4.2.5.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
 - rack-cors (0.4.0) lib/rack/cors.rb:80:in `call'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
 - eventmachine (1.0.9.1) lib/eventmachine.rb:193:in `run'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
 - thin (1.5.1) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:19:in `run'
 - rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
 - railties (4.2.5.1) lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `
```

Thanks.

Comment: could you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Leventix I updated the post with the stacktrace. Thanks

Comment: I think you should contact the authors of the gem, they would probably know what's going on. And post the answer here if you get any.